# What do I need to build a tap handle?

Tags: diy

I'm trying to build a bunch of tap handles, and am a little confused on what I need.

Do I need both of these:

[image: hangar bolt]
[image: ferrule]

[Hangar Bolt](http://morebeer.com/view_product/16296/beerwinecoffee/Hanger_Bolt_-_5_16%22_for_Ferrule) and [Ferrule](http://morebeer.com/view_product/16294/beerwinecoffee/Brass_Ferrule)

or just this:

[image]

[Tap Handle Insert](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/tap-handle-insert.html)

Or something else / other things entirely?

Comment: Brad from [Steel City Tap](https://steelcitytap.com/) gave me free advice on creating tap handles when I called him. I know that's not a typical answer but they make insane tap handles and were willing to provide feedback on making my own which was cool since I only bought a single tap from them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well...yes :)

If you want to have a ferrule on your handle like this:

[image]

then you need the hangar bolt and ferrule.  The hangar bolt has 5/16"-18 male threads on the ferrule side, while the ferrule has 5/16"-18 female threads on the top, and 3/8"-16 female threads on the bottom.

If you want only wood at the bottom of your handle like this:

[image]

then you want the threaded insert (3/8"-16).

Protip: if you're planning on doing several, order your inserts in bags of 10 from a place like McMaster-Carr.  It's a **lot** cheaper that way.

If you want to see how I make taphandles on my lathe, [check out my videos here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL54B262DA0BFAA2D8).

Comment: nice videos. I'm not very good with wood, but with the right tools and craftmanship you made it look easy.

Comment: dang. great answer. how about these guys? http://www.mcmaster.com/#90016a031/=g909ta

Comment: Thank to you both.  @hooked, when I clicked that link it said `3 packs were ordered 04/18/11` underneath them, so I guess they're the right ones :)

Comment: Also I edited the answer with thread sizes for the ferrule.

Comment: @JoeFish I hope so! I never heard back and just assumed they'd work. Already have them in hand. Fast!

Comment: @hookedonwinter, great!  I look forward to pictures :)  Maybe we can get the se.homebrew blog going with some homebrewed projects.

Comment: Final product: http://cdn.denveroffthewagon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/wagon-ryed-tap.jpg

Comment: Wagon ryed!  I see what you did there :)  Nice handle, too!

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I found that Amazon carries packs of 10 threaded inserts cheaper than Mcmaster.
http://www.amazon.com/Threaded-Insert-Threads-Tensile-Strength/dp/B0026GZU0Q/ref=lh_ni_t?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER

Answer (score 2):

I have always preferred the Chrome Ferrules over the brass inserts.  For one it is easier to install the ferrules correctly.  The inserts can sometimes go in a little bit crooked which really throws it off and then the handles is pretty much done fore.
  With the ferrules it's just a matter of drilling a smaller hole and screwing in the bolt.  Also I find the ferrules will go a lot longer before they come loose, if they do at all.  Then it is an easy fix compared to trying to re drill a hole for a brass insert.
  You can buy the [ferrules and hanger bolts](https://www.halfyankeeworkshop.com/collections/tap-handle-parts/products/chrome-ferrule)

Answer (score 1):

I made a few from different scrap pieces of wood and bought some chalk tape. I found the hardware at Lowe's. Check out [my blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20180312151137/http://www.woodworkingfourdummies.com/blog/keg-tap-handle-diy) for pic and details.